# How to insert using mutiple values and SELECT statements?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, insert

I would like to create a query to insert several values along with values that come from other tables, for example:

```
INSERT INTO table
(date, user_id, category_id, title, description)
VALUES
    ((STR_TO_DATE('04-01-2014', '%b-%d-%Y'), 
    (SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = 'admin' LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT id FROM categories WHERE category = 'games' LIMIT 1),
    'title here',
    'description here')
```

This however, gives me an error and from PHP a 500 internal server error. Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table (fields)
SELECT
    str_to_date(),
    users.id,
    categories.id,
    'title',
    'description' 
FROM
    users 
INNER JOIN
    categories ON users.key = categories.key
WHERE
    users.username = 'admin' AND
    categories.category = 'games'
```

that should do it I think...

Comment: Works great only problem is date is not being inserted, any thoughts?

Comment: Will do, thank you. I would vote you up but don't have enough points.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you need a `SELECT` after `VALUES` if you're doing it this way. Try this and see if it works.

```
INSERT INTO table
(date, user_id, category_id, title, description)
VALUES
SELECT 
  STR_TO_DATE('04-01-2014', '%b-%d-%Y'), 
  (SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = 'admin' LIMIT 1),
  (SELECT id FROM categories WHERE category = 'games' LIMIT 1),
  'title here',
  'description here'
```